# Symfony2: blank page and no logs on new Linux machine

Tags: symfony

I deployed my SF2 application on a new machine with RHEL.

Check.php under the "apache" says that the access rights to cache/logs are fine.

However, when calling app.php or app_dev.php I get a blank response, with error code 500 from app.php and 200 from app_dev.php.

No log files are created in app/logs.

Here is the check.php output running for the "apache" user:

```
******************************** 
* * * Symfony requirements check * * * 
******************************** 
php.ini used by PHP: /etc/php.ini 

** WARNING ** 
* The PHP CLI can use a different php.ini file 
* than the one used with your web server. 
* If this is the case, please ALSO launch this 
* utility from your web server. 
** WARNING ** 

** Mandatory requirements ** OK 
Checking that PHP version is at least 5.3.2 (5.3.3 installed) OK 
Checking that the "date.timezone" setting is set OK 
Checking that app/cache/ directory is writable OK 
Checking that the app/logs/ directory is writable OK 
Checking that the json_encode() is available OK 
Checking that the SQLite3 or PDO_SQLite extension is available OK 
Checking that the session_start() is available OK 
Checking that the ctype_alpha() is available OK 
Checking that the token_get_all() is available OK 
Checking that the APC version is at least 3.0.17 ** Optional checks ** OK 
Checking that the PHP-XML module is installed OK 
Checking that the token_get_all() function is available [[WARNING]] 
Checking that the mb_strlen() function is available: FAILED *** Install and enable the mbstring extension *** OK 
Checking that the iconv() function is available OK 
Checking that the utf8_decode() is available [[WARNING]] 
Checking that the posix_isatty() is available: FAILED *** Install and enable the php_posix extension (used to colorized the CLI output) *** [[WARNING]] 
Checking that the intl extension is available: FAILED *** Install and enable the intl extension (used for validators) *** OK 
Checking that a PHP accelerator is installed OK 
Checking that php.ini has short_open_tag set to off OK 
Checking that php.ini has magic_quotes_gpc set to off OK 
Checking that php.ini has register_globals set to off OK 
Checking that php.ini has session.auto_start set to off ** Optional checks (Doctrine) ** OK 
Checking that PDO is installed OK 
Checking that PDO has some drivers installed: pgsql, sqlite
```

***edit***

Thank you for all your hints - but sadly with no effect...

- .htaccess is working
- mod_rewrite is enabled
- display_errors is on
- the apache logs show no errors
- AppKernel path is fine
- $kernel->loadClassCache() in app_dev.php is OK (I get an ouput after that line with *echo*, but there is no response after *handle*

Comment: Did you check the apache logs?

Comment: In your *php.ini*, make sure `display_errors` is enabled. (`html_errors` also if you wish, it's useful)

Comment: apache mod_rewrite enabled?  .htaccess installed? Path to AppKernel set correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault - I was using the ldap bundle, but the php ldap extension was not installed.

And the call to ldap_connect was prefixed with @...

Answer (score 0):

Check the apache logs - you'll probably find them in

```
/var/log/apache2/errors.log
```

Or if you've set a custom logging location in your vhosts

```
/var/log/apache2/errors-your-project.log
```

Calling app_dev.php will probably throw a "you're not allowed to access this from here" error as by default it disallows all access from anywhere except your localhost.

Chances are your vhosts for apache aren't set up quite right.  You'll find them in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/your-project
```

Comment: The error logs from apache show no PHP error. But they work, if I call a php file with a syntax error, the syntax error  is in the apache log.

Comment: I removed the access restriction from app_dev.php, but it gives a blank 200 response.